# SQL Server 2008 R2 attempt to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise on Windows 8.1 and get this error

> 2014-05-13 09:10:37 SSIS: Done adding permissions on folder
>   'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml'. 2014-05-13 09:10:37 SSIS: Done
>   processing folder permissions for SID
>   'S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005' 2014-05-13 09:10:37
>   Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
>   machine  2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry
>   subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTAHostConfig\SSIS_ScriptTask\2.0
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 SSIS: Couldn't open script task registry key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTAHostConfig\SSIS_ScriptTask\2.0 2014-05-13
>   09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTAHostConfig\SSIS_ScriptComponent\2.0 2014-05-13
>   09:10:37 SSIS: Couldn't open script component registry key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTAHostConfig\SSIS_ScriptComponent\2.0 2014-05-13
>   09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine  2014-05-13 09:10:37 SSIS: Processing
>   Registry ACLs for SID 'S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005'
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100 2014-05-13 09:10:37 SSIS:
>   Setting permision on registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100.
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid
>   in security descriptor
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be
>   processed: 
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be
>   returned: 
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to set security descriptor
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security
>   descriptor
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid
>   in security descriptor
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be
>   processed: 
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be
>   returned: 
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize security
>   descriptor
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Sco: Attempting to replace account with sid
>   in security descriptor
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be
>   processed: 
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: ReplaceAccountWithSidInSddl -- SDDL to be
>   returned: 
>   D:(A;OICI;KR;;;S-1-5-21-2280961499-4207575966-3443387993-1005)
>   2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Prompting user if they want to retry this
>   action due to the following failure: 2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------- 2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to
>   innermost order 2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Inner exceptions are being
>   indented 2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp:  2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp: Exception
>   type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException 2014-05-13
>   09:10:37 Slp:     Message:  2014-05-13 09:10:37 Slp:         Attempted
>   to perform an unauthorized operation. 2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:
>   Data:  2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:       WatsonData = 100 2014-05-13
>   09:10:38 Slp:       DisableRetry = true 2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:
>   Inner exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException 2014-05-13
>   09:10:38 Slp:         Message:  2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:
>   Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. 2014-05-13 09:10:38
>   Slp:         Stack:  2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:                 at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo(ResourceType
>   resourceType, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections
>   accessControlSections, RawSecurityDescriptor& resultSd) 2014-05-13
>   09:10:38 Slp:                 at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType
>   resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle,
>   AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName,
>   ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object
>   exceptionContext) 2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:                 at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistrySecurity..ctor(ResourceType
>   resourceType, SafeRegistryHandle handle, AccessControlSections
>   includeSections) 2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:                 at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistrySecurity.Create(InternalRegistryKey
>   key) 2014-05-13 09:10:38 Slp:                 at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.SetSecurityDescriptor(String
>   sddl, Boolean overwrite)

I ever installed in previous laptop, with the same cd and no error.

Any suggestion how to fix this error?

Comment: Help me understand. Is this an installation error or does this present itself when you are opening/designing a package in visual studio?

Comment: @billinkc this is an installation error of sql server 2008 r2

Comment: There is a discussion [here](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqlsetupandupgrade.aspx?ID=61d56f64-2575-4a58-9503-84579476afaf) about what seems like the same issue.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson done, it needs a new administrator account, it's quite strange, my account is already administrator. Do you know why? Anyway thanks for your help, please write an answer so I could appreciate your help

Comment: @Willy Sadly, I have no idea about the actual problem, I just used my Google-foo and realized it was better to send you to a page with some discussion than try to guess which of the solutions would help you.